# Passing string through Controller on ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to pass a serial number (or ESN) back from my current page and into a new page. I'm attempting to do so by calling this code on my first page.

**View 1**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "InventoryDetails", "ItemReconcilliation", new {ESN = mySerialNumber})
```

Where `mySerialNumber` is a variable that is verified to have good data.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult InventoryDetails(HistoryModel model, string ESN)
{
    model = new HistoryModel (ESN);
    return View(model);
}
```

However, my `ESN` variable is always coming back as null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have the HistoryModel argument in your method, I don't think you need it. Just create a new HistoryModel in the method body.

As for the ActionLink, from memory you need an extra null argument on the end of the ActionLink like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "InventoryDetails", "ItemReconcilliation", new {ESN = mySerialNumber},null)
```

and it should render properly.

EDIT: 
Your initial method should be something like this:

```
public ActionResult InventoryDetails(string ESN)
{
   HistoryModel viewModel = new HistoryModel(ESN);
   return View(viewModel);
}
```

followed by this method where you actually submit your form/model to your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InventoryDetails(HistoryModel viewModel)
{
   //do work with viewModel, such as saving it to the database.

   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

If you wanted to add a html class/attribute to the ActionLink then thats what you would replace the `null` with. For example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details","InventoryDetails", "ItemReconcilliation", new { ESN = mySerialNumber }, new { @class = "snazzyCSSStyleClass" })
```

Comment: I'm new to MVC/Razor, so I'm still trying to figure out exactly how it's all connected - I'll try removing the HistoryModel from the method body and see what happens - wouldn't I need to define `model` then in that case?

Also, adding the extra null argument worked... any idea why, or any links on information as to why that's the case?